# How to filter rows based on tuple values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, tuples, associations

I am using `mlxtend` to find association rules:

Here is the code:

```
df = apriori(dum_data, min_support=0.5, use_colnames=True)
rules = association_rules(df, metric="lift", min_threshold=1)
rules2=rules[ (rules['lift'] >= 1) & (rules['confidence'] >= 0.8) ]
```

Output:

```
antecedents     consequents
( A,B,C)          (D)
(A)               (B)
(C,D,R)           (A) 
(C,D,F,G)         (E)
(A,E)             (B)

The type of values is `frozenset`
```

I want to keep only those rows whose `antecedents` doesn't have `A` or `E` and `consequent` has `A` or `E`

```
Final output:

antecedents     consequents
(C,D,R)           (A) 
(C,D,F,G)         (E)
```

Comment: @desertnaut Any help?

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do just that:

```
condition_1 = df['antecedents'].apply(lambda x: 'A' not in x and 'E' not in x)
condition_2 = df['consequents'].apply(lambda x: 'A' in x or 'E' in x)

df.loc[condition_1 & condition_2]
```

I hope this helps!